# How to calculate the center of a regular polygon?

Tags: metric-geometry, polygons

What is the formula for the center of an `n`-edge regular polygon that has the given segment as its edge?

So, given a segment `AB`, with endpoints `A=(a1,a2)` and `B=(b1,b2)`, I need to find out the two points `X=(x1,x2)` and `Y=(y1,y2)`, such that the `n`-edge regular polygon with center at `X`, and the one with center at `Y` have `AB` as their edge.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T=\tan(180^{\circ}/n)$.  The midpoint of $AB$ is $((a1+b1)/2,(a2+b2)/2)$, the centres would be 
 $$((a1+b1)/2+(a2-b2)/2T,(a2+b2)/2+(b1-a1)/2T)\\
((a1+b1)/2+(b2-a2)/2T,(a2+b2)/2+(a1-b1)/2T)$$